# Minimizing I/O in a PostgreSQL benchmark

Tags: postgresql, buffer, wal

I am running some experiments with PostgreSQL, and it's all for the purpose of learning how Postgres works underneath, and there's no production value to what I'm testing. I'm just fiddling around with the system.

I have two machines, a client and server, and I'm using benchbase for TPCC benchmarking.
I have made some configurations to essentially zero out the disk usage, but I am seeing disk usage by the backends using `iotop` and `iostat`. Also `inotifywait` is reporting a lot of modified files on disk.

My goal is to maximize CPU usage and minimize IO. Obviously I can't achieve the former without achieving the latter.

I will describe my problem in further detail:

I am using `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE` in my DDL to minimize WAL writes.
The data directory is almost 10GB (100 TPCC warehouses, although I have experimented with numbers as big as 1000 previously without any difference in the final outcome), all of which is in the `base` directory. `pg_wal` is empty at the beginning of the experiment, which is expected.

I am running with `READ COMMITTED` isolation level to minimize transaction serialization overhead.

I set these configurations to make sure everything fits in memory:
(Disclaimer for people who stumble upon this question later: these configs are not suitable for a real database system in production at all)

```
shared_buffers = 128GB 
checkpoint_timeout = 1d
synchronous_commit = off
work_mem = 6MB
max_wal_senders = 0
wal_level = minimal 
full_page_writes = off 
fsync = off
autovacuum = off 
bgwriter_flush_after = 0        # measured in pages, 0 disables
```

As the first workload, I only use TPCC queries that have `SELECT` queries exclusively. No writes.
The CPU utilization is very close to 100% in all cores (using 150 terminals (backends)).
Disk utilization is 0%, and `inotifywait` only reports a negligible number of writes to `pg_stat` files.

On the other hand, if I run the original TPCC workload where most queries are either `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s, the results are wildly different.

CPU util doesn't go above 40% except for a few cores which show around 60%, and here's the disk util with a 2 second resolution:
[Disk Util Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRVah.png)

Interestingly, there is a 225MB `pg_wal` directory in the data dir afterwards.
I put logs in the `FlushBuffer` function in `bufmgr.c`, and nobody is writing out dirty buffers to disk. At least not until I stop the server I don't see those logs.

I used `pg_stats`, here's the output of `pg_stat_wal`:
[pg_stat_wal output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdm7i.png)
(I have also run experiments where `track_activities` is off altogether to get rid of the overhead)

So as it looks like, the culprit is WAL. But WHY? The tables are `UNLOGGED`. Who is writing this? What am I missing in the buffer manager implementation?

I've tried with different combinations of the configs I mentioned above, but I'm sure I'm missing something that a Postgres pro can help with.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to use one of the WAL decoder libraries to gain more insight. But, don't forget that any changes to system catalogues will be logged

Comment: "Also inotifywait is reporting a lot of modified files on disk"  Ok, but what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Every transaction commit writes a COMMIT record into the WAL stream; even if every table touched in the transaction was UNLOGGED.  In your case the writing out of this record should be asynchronous (for multiple reasons, the tables being unlogged, plus synchronous_commit being off, plus fsync being off), but it still exists.

But you have no evidence that this is the bottleneck.  Your reasoning seems to be "CPU <100%, and IO is happening, so it must be the fault of IO", but that is not valid.  The bottleneck could be IPC overhead, lock contention, spinlock contention, etc.  Just because IO is not nonexistent doesn't mean that it is the cause of the bottleneck.

If you look at `top` output, there should be a line something like this:

```
%Cpu(s): 19.2 us, 64.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  2.3 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi, 13.9 si,  0.0 st
```

In this case, even though a lot of IO is happening, things only spend 0.6% of their time waiting on it--it mostly happens in the background.  Most of their time is spend waiting on the system, which I think is mostly driven by context switches, not directly by IO (although IO is one of the things that can cause context switches).

If you want a quick and dirty test of this, you could put the database, or just pg_wal, on a RAM disk, such as /dev/shm, and see how things do or don't change.

Also, 150 backends seems like overkill, unless each one has some "think time" built into its workload. Is it necessary to have so many of them in order to get maximal CPU usage?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will test with RAM disk.
I'm testing on a highly multicore system so 150 backend processes does not incur any drastic context switch overhead since I have more (logical) cores. At least that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @eagle4231  Is logical cores the same thing as hyperthreading?  I generally find that that is more for marketing than for performance. Test different numbers of terminals, and see where the throughput stops increasing much.  I suspect it will be before 150, either because your core count is fake, or due to contention.  Also, make sure you use the latest version of PostgreSQL, as improvements have been made recently to benefit high core count machines.

Comment: My machine has 96 cores, 192 hyperthreads. I just used `taskset` to make sure i wasn't using hyperthreading. I reduced the number of terminals to 90, and I'm getting the same results. `htop` and my own plots showing 90%+ CPU for read-only workloads, while much less in the original TPCC + IO util increasing from 0 to around 20 at the peaks. But you raise a good comment that my reasoning here is problematic. I'm drawing flamegraphs, any way to find out who is doing IO and if it is causing the issue using those?

Comment: Here's how my `top` looks though: ```%Cpu(s): 18.0 us,  2.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 78.8 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.0 st```. A lot of idling. What exactly counts as that?

Comment: Same issue is happening with only 5 terminals. CPU util in read-only is no longer 100, but it is significantly higher than the other workload. The main difference here is: there is no longer a big difference between IO.

Comment: quick update. I was able to get more CPU by simply using benchmarksql instead of benchbase. Exact same benchmarks and configs. However, the clients were using a different socket on the same machine rather than being on a different machine (didnt work the other way around). I cannot achieve the same result if I run my benchbase client code on the same machine though. I don’t have a definitive explanation yet but at least theres some progress.